# Shorthand for wrapping a swift variable in an optional?

Tags: swift, variables, syntax, casting, option-type

Swift allows us to use the shorthand notation `str!` to unwrap an optional. But what if we want to do the opposite?

Say I have a variable:

```
var str = String() // String
```

Is there any shorthand notation to convert this to an optional (i.e. `String?` or `String!`)?

(E.g. I want to do something like `var strOptional = ?(str)`.)

Alternatively, if there is no shorthand for this notation, how can I convert it to an optional without explicitly mentioning its type (e.g. I don't want to mention `String`).

In other words, I know that I can wrap a variable as an optional with any of these methods:

```
var strOptional = str as String?
var strOptional: String? = str
var strOptional = String?(str)
```

... but in each case, I must explicitly write `String`.

I would rather write something like: `var strOptional = str as typeof?(str)`, if there is no shorthand syntax. (The advantage is that if the variable's type is frequently changed in the code base, it would be one less place to update.)

---

As far as a real world example of where this would be useful, imagine I want to use an AVCaptureDevice and I use the following code:

```
let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
device.lockForConfiguration(nil)
```

`lockForConfiguration()` will crash at runtime on a device that has no video camera, and the compiler won't warn me about it. The reason is that `defaultDeviceWithMediaType` may return `nil` according to the documentation<sup>[1]</sup>, yet it is defined to return a `AVCaptureDevice!`.

To fix a faulty API like this, it would be nice to do something like:

```
let device = ?(AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo))
```

... to get a `AVCaptureDevice?`, and have the compiler catch any mistakes I might make.

Currently, I must resort to the more verbose:

```
let device: AVCaptureDevice? = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
```

---

Another example:

In this case, I want to give a default value to my variable that is a string, but later on, I may want to assign it a `nil` value.

```
var myString = "Hi"
// ...
if (someCondition()) {
    myString = nil // Syntax error: myString is String
}
```

Currently I have to resort to `var myString: String? = "Hi"` but something like `var myString = ?("Hi")` would be less verbose.

---

<sub>[1] If you open AVCaptureDevice.h, you will see the following documentation about the return value: "The default device with the given media type, or nil if no device with that media type exists."</sub>

Comment: Hmm, I deleted my answer.  You have enough rep to still see it.  Most of my answer still applies, but I think `AVCaptureDevice` is a holdout.  When Apple first introduced Swift, basically *everything* returned implicitly unwrapped optionals, but they're supposed to be converting all of these over to either non-optionals or regular optionals.  That's what the Objective-C nullability macros are for.

Comment: @nhgrif: Thanks for the comments. I added another example of where this might be useful which doesn't involve Apple's frameworks.

Comment: In your second example, I think it's important to be explicit with your type.  There's a reason Apple didn't bring preprocessor macros into Swift...

Comment: I agree with @nhgrif on both points. AVFoundation just isn't ported yet. And the latter is clear as `let myString = Optional("Hi")` (that doesn't work for `!` types, though). I wouldn't oppose some simple syntax if someone comes up with one, but I certainly wouldn't create an operator or anything heavy like that. You could wrap it up easily in a function called `lift` that takes an optional or a non-optional and returns an optional.

Answer (score 4):

Optional is just an enum in swift, so you can do: `Optional(str)`

From the swift interface:

```
/// A type that can represent either a `Wrapped` value or `nil`, the absence
/// of a value.
public enum Optional<Wrapped> : _Reflectable, NilLiteralConvertible {
    case None
    case Some(Wrapped)
    /// Construct a `nil` instance.
    public init()
    /// Construct a non-`nil` instance that stores `some`.
    public init(_ some: Wrapped)
    /// If `self == nil`, returns `nil`.  Otherwise, returns `f(self!)`.
    @warn_unused_result
    public func map<U>(@noescape f: (Wrapped) throws -> U) rethrows -> U?
    /// Returns `nil` if `self` is `nil`, `f(self!)` otherwise.
    @warn_unused_result
    public func flatMap<U>(@noescape f: (Wrapped) throws -> U?) rethrows -> U?
    /// Create an instance initialized with `nil`.
    public init(nilLiteral: ())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To wrap up a variable you could use operator overloading and generic functions. For example:

```
prefix operator ??? {}

prefix func ??? <T> (x: T) -> T? {
    return Optional(x)
}
```

To relate this to your second example, you would do the following:

```
var myString = ???"Hi" // Optional("Hi")

if someCondition() {
    myString = nil
}
```

Comment: I was working on the exact same answer.  This doesn't solve the problem of a function that returns an explicitly unwrapped optional that you want to treat as a regular optional.  For example, if `func test()->Int! { return 17 }` is called like so, `let a = ??test()`, then `a` will have the type `Int!?` instead of `Int?`.

Comment: Isn't "??" a bad choice of operator, seeing as how that's the symbol for the nil coalescing operator?

Answer (score 0):

In the lighthearted spirit that, as I understand, the question was posed, you can define a postfix operator that uses one character less than your ideal solution (a pair of parens and a question mark):

```
postfix operator =? {}
postfix func =? <T> (rhs: T) -> T? { return rhs }
postfix func =? <T> (rhs: T!) -> T? { return rhs ?? nil }

var x = 3=?
x is Int? //--> true

var imp: Int! = 3
var opt = imp=?
opt is Int? //--> true
```

As to Apple's APIs you mention, since they already return an optional, albeit an implicitly unwrapped optional, you could use the nil coalescing operator `??` to convert it to a plain optional:

```
let y: Int! = 3 // posing for a rogue API 

y is Int? //--> false

let z = y ?? nil

z is Int? //--> true
```

Perhaps a sligtly more interesting use of a dodgy operator is a higher order operator function that lifts `T -> U`s into `T? -> U?`s...

```
func opt <T, U> (f: T -> U) -> T? -> U? { // we'll implement this as an operator
    return { $0.map(f) }
}

postfix operator ->? {}
postfix func ->? <T, U> (f: T -> U) -> T? -> U? {
    return { $0.map(f) }
}
```

Now, let's use it:

```
let square: Int -> Int = { $0 * $0 }

let i: Int? = 3

square->? (i)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
opt(square)(i)
```

Which is equivalent to (but potentially a little more versatile than):

```
i.map(square)
```

This all makes much more sense when used along with the pipe forward operator:

```
infix operator |> { associativity left precedence 89 }
func |> <A, B>(a: A, f: A -> B) -> B {
    return f(a)
}
```

Then you can do:

```
i |> opt(square)
```

or

```
i |> square->?
```

Or we can conflate these into an optional pipe forward, which can take care of implicitly unwrapped optionals too:

```
infix operator ?> { associativity left precedence 89 }
func ?> <T, U> (lhs: T?, rhs: T -> U) -> U? {
    return lhs.map(rhs)
}

let im: Int! = 5
let op: Int? = 5

im ?> square |> debugPrintln //--> Optional(25)
op ?> square |> debugPrintln //--> Optional(25)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
debugPrintln(op.map(square))
```